# How do I call a method when I have not defined a variable name?

Tags: python, object

I'm trying to figure out how I call a method on a unnamed variable so that I am able to test my methods without having to create objects. I think you invoke it on the class? But I'm unsure of how to do so..

```
class Base: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Base'

    def foo(self):
        return 'ball'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x
```

I want to be able to say print(Base.foo()) in another class without creating a new object

Comment: You create an unnamed instance: `print(Base().foo())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a class method.

```
class Base: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Base'

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return 'ball'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x
```

Comment: Nvm it was simply print(Base().foo())

Comment: Since you were actually asking the question with Base.foo(), I believe I answered correctly.

Comment: @crunch: Base().foo() is instancing a new object of type Base, which is what you said you did NOT want to do.